# How to update ApolloClient authorization header after successful login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, local-storage, graphql

Basically, we have this in our `index.js` file to set-up the `ApolloProvider` authorization to make queries / mutations.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

let session = localStorage.getItem("session");
let authorization = "";
if(session) {
    let sessionObj = JSON.parse(session);
    authorization = sessionObj.access_token
}

const graphQLServerURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: graphQLServerURL + "/graphql",
    headers: {
       authorization,
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

When the app first loads, the `authorization` header would be `null`. However, within the `<App>` component, we have a `<Login>` component which basically does a post request with a `username` and `password`. Upon successful request in the `.then()` method, we have:

```
.then(res => {
if (res === 200) {
    localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(res.data));
    history.push("/dashboard");
});
```

So what happens is the user is redirected to a `<Dashboard>` component which has a `<Query>` component (to list some data). However, the `authorization` in `ApolloClient` is still `null` until I hit refresh. Using `push` doesn't reload the `<App>` component (so that it gets the updated `session` from localstorage).

How should I do this in a way that after successful post request on login, the authorization from `index.js` gets the latest `session` object without having to reload the entire application?

Comment: It appears that the Apollo Client 3 docs show how to include a header on each call. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header

ncabral below has the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `request` function if you use `apollo-boost`

```
const getToken = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
};

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `${graphQLServerURL}/graphql`,
  request: (operation) => {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: getToken(),
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: If you're using Apollo Client 3 you should check out the answer below by ncabral that uses Apollo Client's setContext. That answer is referenced in the latest Apollo Client API docs (see the REF link in ncabral's answer).

Answer (score 9):

You will have to use a link. [Ref](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication#header)

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
});
```

Comment: However, our app is using `ApolloClient` from `apollo-boost` and it doesn't recognise the `link` option.

Comment: Dang, wish this wouldn't have been downvoted.  With new Apollo Client 3 this is the preferred path and would have saved me time.  Totally skipped this answer due to down votes >.>

Comment: @afreeland agreed, this answer is highly underated.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to "**update** ApolloClient authorization header after successful login". This answer assumes you are already logged in. What this question is asking for is that you have already created `ApolloClient` **without** a token. Then you login and somehow pass that token to the existing `ApolloClient`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to use the `token` into `ApolloProvider`. When the app was rendering for the first time I could not access the `localStorage` as a result the WebSocket could not work.

#### What I did?

I created a custom hook and used both `useEffect` and `useState` to update it.

```js
import {
  ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink, split,
} from '@apollo/client';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import config from './index';

export const useConfigClient = () => {
  const [authTokenStorage, setAuthTokenStorage] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'));   // by default it is null

  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: config.GRAPHQL_URL,
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${authTokenStorage}`,
    },
  });

  const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
    uri: config.GRAPHQL_WS,
    options: {
      reconnect: true,
      connectionParams: {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${authTokenStorage}`,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const link = split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
      return (
        definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition'
        && definition.operation === 'subscription'
      );
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setAuthTokenStorage(localStorage.getItem('token')); // as soon as it is available just update the token
  }, []);

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link,
  });

  return client;
};
```

#### How I used the custom hook?

```js
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { useConfigClient } from '../config/apolloConfig';  // import the hooks

<ApolloProvider client={useConfigClient()}>
  //  ... add your component
</ ApolloProvider>
```

I am not sure it is the best way to fix it. For now, it works and I hope it will help others.

Comment: When I use this, I get an Invalid Hook Error. "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." which makes sense as the function being used here is not a component.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is that you can use `setLink` method from apollo-config.
After that, export a function that'll set the headers once you had your token.

```js
import {ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink} from '@apollo/client';
import {setContext} from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: '/graphql'});

let config = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export function setGraphqlHeaders() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
  const authLink = setContext((_, {headers}) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token || null,
      },
    };
  });

  config.setLink(authLink.concat(httpLink));
}
```

Hope, this'll help someone

Comment: Thanks @praveen-me. This is the simplest solution. I added an argument "setGraphqlHeaders(token:string)" since the caller provides the token.

Answer (score 1):

`praveen-me`'s answer works for me in 2021 with Nextjs. I tried the `ncabral`'s answer but I not sure it will automatically update the JWT for me.

On top of `praveen-me`'s answer, I added something to the code for me:

*userToken.ts*

```
const userTokenKey = 'userToken'

export const getUserToken = () => {
    try {
        return localStorage.getItem(userTokenKey)   
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
}

export const setUserToken = (token: string) => {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(userTokenKey, token)
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

*apolloClient.ts*

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { getUserToken } from "./userToken";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_URL
})

let client = new ApolloClient({
    // link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export function updateGraphqlHeaders() {
    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
        const token = getUserToken();
        return {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
            }
        }
    })
    client.setLink(authLink.concat(httpLink))
}
updateGraphqlHeaders() // Init

export default client;
```

*_app.tsx*

```
...
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "../auth/apolloClient";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

First create layout.tsx

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client"; 
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }:any) {

    const client = createApolloClient();
     
    return (
    <html lang="en">
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>  
      
      </ApolloProvider>  
    </html>
  )
}
```

you need to create apollo-client.js

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { getUserToken } from "./userToken";

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: API_URL,
});


const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists  
  const userToken = await getUserToken()  
  const token =  userToken || null;
  
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const createApolloClient = () => {
    
    let client = '';    
    client = new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    }); 
    return client  
};

export default createApolloClient;
```

create userToken.js

```
export const getUserToken = () => { 
    try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

this is working for me if any then please comment